# Use scanner input to initialize an object and also try and catch for invalid input or mismatch - java

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to use a Scanner object to initialize the fields of an object(buyer object), and also use a try and catch to check for invalid input, also want to put the try and catch inside a while loop, so it will keep asking the user for the right input until they put it, I seem to be having a variable scope problem, as I've been getting errors like variable is not defined and unreachable code.

```
    if(userResponse4.equals("buyer")) {
        
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String dateOfBirth;
        String local;
        double funds;
        short creditScore;
        long personID;
        
        
         while (true) {
           try {
                     
               System.out.println("Enter your first Name");
                 firstName = sc4.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter your Last Name");
                 lastName = sc4.next();
                System.out.print("Enter your Date Of Birth");
                  dateOfBirth = sc4.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Local info");
                 local = sc4.next();
                System.out.print("Enter Your Credit Score");
                creditScore = sc4.nextShort();
                System.out.println("Enter your account balance");
                  funds = sc4.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter your IDnumber \n");
             personID = sc4.nextLong();

                }
                catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the right input type");
                }
                Buyer buyer = new Buyer(personID, firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, local, funds, creditScore);
                System.out.println(buyer);
            }

        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Which variable is not defined?  Since this is only a code snippet we can't see what you have defined (we'd need the entire code listing for that).

Comment: sorry I meant variable have not been initialized, the variables inside the buyer object(personID, firstName, last name etc)

Comment: add error logs please

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Buyer initialization outside the while loop. Right now, if you error out, you never actually have the variables initialized to anything. Once you put it outside the while loop, only the try-catch code will run, which should solve your issue. Hope this helps!